# Json vs html.erb in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, erb

My project is on ruby on rails.
I have one of ruby api  returns json.jbuilder.
But I want that my api should not return json , it will display html.erb file.
Is anybody can help me???

Comment: FYI - we appreciate if you show some research first. You should take a quick look at the [layout guide for Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html). It will help you to understand how to return a normal html template.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is not recommended to forcefully respond with html template for a `json` request or vice versa.

I hope you have enough reasons for this which are best known to you.

Anyways, if you want to forcefully process a particular request as html, you can append .html in the end of request url.

e.g. If you want to process index action of `users` controller 
 whose url is
`http://localhost:3000/users`

To achieve it 
Call controller action with url 
`http://localhost:3000/users.html`, 
 controller will treat request as html and it will respond with html(you will need to have a html template for your controller action).

Similarly if you want to respond json for any request, append `.json` to the request url, 
`http://localhost:3000/users.json`

controller will treat request as json and it will respond with json(you will need to have a json template for your controller action).